# How can I stop from Magento from returning all products with non-sense search queries?

Tags: search, magento, full-text-search, magento-1.4

Currently, on my Magento store, a user can search anything in the main search bar and it will return every product in the database. So if I sell nail polish, and the user types in "tom cruise" the user will get a list of every single product. I want to fix this so that if a user types in something that there isn't a match for the user get no results.

I'm running Magento 1.4.2.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the admin menu *System > Index Management* and rebuild all the indexes. Then do the same for *System > Cache Management*. Does the problem still exist?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried what you suggested and the problem still exists.

Comment: I had to actually manually delete the cache in the /var folder for it to finally work. Thank you =)